# How can I compare two objects of same class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, object

I want to know how can I compare two objects (which is of the same class) like the `string.Compare()` method.

**Is there any way to do this?**

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183929/comparing-two-objects

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The duplicate is the wrong one: The question asks about *comparing* two objects the same way `string.Compare` does, while the duplicate asks about *equating* two objects. The most voted answer here exactly answers what's being asked.

Answer (score 10):

You can implement `IComparable` interface, like sugested [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727):

```
public class Temperature : IComparable 
{
    // The temperature value 
    protected double temperatureF;

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Temperature otherTemperature = obj as Temperature;
        if (otherTemperature != null) 
            return this.temperatureF.CompareTo(otherTemperature.temperatureF);
        else 
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Temperature");
    }
  ...
```

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You will have `CompareTo` method which will compare items of your class. More on `IComparable` can be found here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/c-sharp-interfaces-how-to-implement-icomparable). Having `CompareTo` you can sort lists of your objects according to comparision function like mentioned [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42839/Sorting-Lists-using-IComparable-and-IComparer-Inte)

Answer (score 2):

since objects are reference types, so you should use **obj.Equals()** method.
also note that:

```
string.ReferenceEquals(str, str2);
```

It obviously compares references.

```
str.Equals(str2)
```

Tries to compare references at first. Then it tries to compare by value.

```
str == str2
```

Does the same as Equals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the IComparable interface.

```
private class sortYearAscendingHelper : IComparer
{
   int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
   {
      car c1=(car)a;
      car c2=(car)b;
      if (c1.year > c2.year)
         return 1;
      if (c1.year < c2.year)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
   }
}
```

*Original post can be found* [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727)

Answer (score 1):

You can check two equality Reference Equality and Value Equality

**Reference equality**

Reference equality means that two object references refer to the same underlying object. This can occur through simple assignment, as shown in the following example.

```
class Test
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        Test a = new Test() { Num = 1, Str = "Hi" };
        Test b = new Test() { Num = 1, Str = "Hi" };

        bool areEqual = System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b);
        // Output will be false
        System.Console.WriteLine("ReferenceEquals(a, b) = {0}", areEqual);

        // Assign b to a.
        b = a;

        // Repeat calls with different results.
        areEqual = System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b);
        // Output will be true
        System.Console.WriteLine("ReferenceEquals(a, b) = {0}", areEqual);


    }
}
```

**Value equality**

Value equality means that two objects contain the same value or values. For primitive value types such as int or bool, tests for value equality are straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

//Generic Comparer
public class EntityComparer<T> :  IEqualityComparer<T>, IComparer<T> 
where T : BaseEntity
{
    public enum AscDesc : short
    {
        Asc, Desc
    }

    #region Const
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public AscDesc SortType { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public EntityComparer(string _propertyname = "Id", AscDesc _sorttype = AscDesc.Asc)
    {
        this.PropertyName = _propertyname;
        this.SortType = _sorttype;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IComparer
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetProperty(PropertyName) == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("{0} does not contain a property with the name \"{1}\"", typeof(T).Name, PropertyName));

        var xValue = (IComparable)x.GetType().GetProperty(this.PropertyName).GetValue(x, null);
        var yValue = (IComparable)y.GetType().GetProperty(this.PropertyName).GetValue(y, null);

        if (this.SortType == AscDesc.Asc)
            return xValue.CompareTo(yValue);

        return yValue.CompareTo(xValue);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEqualityComparer
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetProperty(PropertyName) == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("{0} does not contain a property with the name -> \"{1}\"", typeof(T).Name, PropertyName));

        var valuex = x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(x, null);
        var valuey = y.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(y, null);

        if (valuex == null) return valuey == null;

        return valuex.Equals(valuey);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        var info = obj.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);
        object value = null;
        if (info != null)
        {
            value = info.GetValue(obj, null);
        }

        return value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
    }
    #endregion
}

 //Usage
 Product product = new Product();
 Product product2 =new Product();
 EntityComparer<Product> comparer = new EntityComparer<Product>("Propert Name Id Name whatever u want", Asc Or Desc);
 comparer.Compare(product, product2);
```